# how to call a class and its function in another file class

Tags: php

```
   include 'upload.php';
   $attachments = new $uploads();
   $file = $uploads->uploadAttachment();
   $this->file->uploadAttachment();
```

Uploads is a class name in upload.Php file.
Here I am getting this error:

```
  Notice: Undefined variable
  Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string
```

Please help me where I did mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've putted a $ before `uploads();` when you initialize a class you need to use the exact class name so this should work:  `$attachments = new uploads();`

Answer (score 0):

Class names do not use the `$` character. You need to do this:

```
$attachments = new Uploads();
```

`new $uploads()` actually means "create a new object of the class named in the variable `$uploads`". Since `$uploads` is undefined, no class is created and the errors you see are thrown.

Comment: Thank you..still it is not executing the condition in uploadAttachment() function